# Wrap text in css3 columns

Tags: html, css

I have a long text that I want to show in a newspaper-like manner, e.g. inside columns, to the user. This improves readability. However if a line is longer than a column's width, words are cut off, e.g. hidden behind the column to the right. I need to wrap those lines, inside the column, to make all text visible.

Here is my code so far:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable>
    Testdiv (insert long text here)
</div>
```

css:

```
#editor{
/* span the editor's content automatically above multiple columns: */    
    -webkit-columns: 300px 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-columns: 300px 3; /* Firefox */
    columns: 300px 3;

    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
       -moz-column-gap: 20px;
            column-gap: 20px;

/* wrap text that does not fit into one column: <-- Does not work as expected */ 
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

**Update**
I uploaded an image of the problem.
Inside the image you can see the new css (only 2 columns). But it did not change. The code from the fiddle was what I found out initially before trying to adapt to my use case, because there it was working for me, too. I am rendering with chrome engine, if that matters.

[image]

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/r6z63uLb/)**

Comment: as I can see it work normally [https://jsfiddle.net/ocfpc8ga/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/ocfpc8ga/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The words aren't getting cut off behind the next column, they're wrapping on a character basis. That's what `break-all` does. Try `break-word` instead.

```css
#editor {
    /* span the editor's content automatically above multiple columns: */
    -webkit-columns: 300px 3;
    /* Chrome, Safari1 Opera */
    -moz-columns: 100px 3;
    /* Firefox */
    columns: 100px 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 30px;
    -moz-column-gap: 30px;
    column-gap: 30px;
    /* wrap text that does not fit into one column: <-- Does not work as expected */
    word-break: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable>
    Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) Testdiv (insert long text here) 
</div>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/r6z63uLb/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

It works as intended by the CSS, but it breaks all words at line ends now, that's your problem.

I would recommend to erase those word-break and white-space settings and put "soft hyphens" into very long words (usually there aren't that many extra-long words which are longer than a line, and IMO a broken word without a hyphen doesn't look good at all):

A `&shy;` entity in the middle of a word will break the word if necessary and remain invisible if the word fits into a line.

Example:

```
qwertzuiopüasd&shy;fghjklöäyxcvbnm
```

will display as

```
qwertzuiopüasdfghjklöäyxcvbnm
```

when it fully fits into a line, and will be displayed as

```
qwertzuiopüasd-
fghjklöäyxcvbnm
```

when the lines are shorter than this word.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking in readability perspective, Then add this CSS to yours

```
 word-break: break-word;
 text-align: justify;
```

It will only break **words** not **characters** and will justify to fit complete width.

**This will even wraps your long texts to next line**